# Mount permissions problems

Tags: disk-management, mount, permissions

when I tried to mount and other ssd in my elementary os I had get this problem:
All the files with no permission, seems like they are being mounted as root, but why?

I trid to follow this another topic: [NAS share mount permission problems](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/28990/nas-share-mount-permission-problems) , but without success.

this is my fstab file:

```
  GNU nano 4.8                                                                                                      etc/fstab                                                                                                                
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system>  <mount point>  <type>  <options>  <dump>  <pass>
PARTUUID=89a21891-8b81-4bb6-b362-5798978f99f1  /boot/efi  vfat  umask=0077,uid=1000,gid=1000  0       0
UUID=c3261c9f-cb24-4dc4-a2a2-bd7df74cca76  /  ext4  noatime,errors=remount-ro  0  0
/dev/disk/by-uuid/290B3424686AD77F /mnt/arquivos/290B3424686AD77F auto nodev,gid=1000,uid=1000,nounix,nofail,x-gvfs-show,\040 0 0
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Can't comment (weird Stack rules...) so here is a question:

why do you have backward slash in your fstab line?:

> gid=1000,uid=1000,nounix,nofail,x-gvfs-show,\040 0 0